# odoo14 CE: Restrict merging of picking for same destination and same products

Tags: transfer, odoo-14, inventory-management

> By default odoo 14 CE merge the picking for the same destination and
> for the products. Is there a way / configuration / settings / codes
> that can "RESTRICT MERGING" of picking and products.
>
> Example Case:
>
> I have Warehouse A & B and I want to send Internal Transfer via
> Transit Warehouse with 1 step with pull rule from Transit/A to B/IN/01
> {Delivery Operation Receipt}. I create a A/INT/01 to Transit/A which
> odoo will create 3 transfers as follows
>
> A/INT/01 to Transit/A >> Ready Transit/A to B/IN/01 >> Waiting
> another operation B/IN/01 to B/Stock >> Waiting another operation If
> followed step by step operation everything works fine but if I create
> another transfer from A to B say as follows,
>
> A/INT/02 to Transit/A >> Ready Transit/A to B/IN/01 >> Waiting
> another operation B/IN/01 to B/Stock >> Waiting another operation
> Notice: Transfer A/INT/02 will be merged in existing Transit/A this is
> also fine but it will not create B/INT/02 instead all products will be
> merged in B/IN/01 and odoo will not create B/IN/02
>
> What I am doing wrong in Transit configuration or how to stop merging
> products and picking?
>
> Reason why I need to use "Transit" is >> I need steps for Internal
> transfer [Pick+Pack+Ship] as products will be scanned with barcode
> reader on every step which is NOT AVAILABLE in Internal Transfer.

Comment: Its been 5 days now, no one has replied. Disappointed from the community. Let me know if something which is not clear or missing anything in mentioning detail.

Comment: Update:
I fixed my issue to restrict merging "Picking" by "Procurement Group" sequence entry for each transfer. In debug mode , Inventory >> Operation >> Transfers >> Create Transfer . In transfer >> open "Additional Info" > Procurement Group [Its read-only by default] make it editable > create procurement group
As every Transfer will be having distinct procurement group, it will not merge anymore!

Answer (score 0):

i made Procurement Group Editable, i now can select the Procurement Group but still merging pickking

Comment: Hello if u can explain ur situation then may i can help u out.