# Preventing internal transfer merge

Tags: stock, inventory, odoo-15, picking

When creating multiple internal transfer, Odoo merges all transfers into one, which is very inconvenient for us.

After looking at this [posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74935408/odoo14-ce-restrict-merging-of-picking-for-same-destination-and-same-products/77571479), the issue seems to be related to the "Procurement Group" field.

However, even after changing the field and make it editable, as per OP's update, it still merges internal transfers together and the auto created "Receipt" transfer has an empty "Procurement Group" field and doesn't get that info from the source document for some reason.

When creating an internal transfer to another warehouse, a "Receipt" is created automatically in that warehouse. Creating multiple internal transfer to the same warehouse should create multiple "Receipts" and not merging the new ones with the old one.

Can anyone help with this or provide some tips on how to proceed to fix this issue?